# Why are my @media queries not being registered by the code editor when they come after a certain line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I've looked through the various similar questions and have not found an answer. I have these media queries, and I found that they are not being applied after a certain point. The ones up till @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { are working, but after that nothing is being applied. I tried taking the code below that @media query and put them above it, and Then they work, but then this one stops working. I'm not sure why it's doing that. Any ideas?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
    .provider-specialty h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }

}

/*---laptop 1366---*/
@media (mi`n-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1499.98px) {
    .nav-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 80px 60px;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .content-box-page {
        height: 476px;
        margin: 80px 60px 40px 70px;
    }

    #provider-content img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .provider-specialty {
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
    .provider-specialty h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }

}

/*--- XLarge Devices laptop1280(desktop/laptop)--*/

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1365.98px) {
    .nav-item {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .content-box-md {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 80px 60px;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .content-box-page {
        height: 476px;
        margin: 80px 60px 20px 70px;
    }
    #provider-content img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .provider-specialty {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-left: 90px;

    }
    #provider-contact {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .provider-specialty h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }


}

/*--- Large Devices (landscape tablets/medium desktop)IpadAir2 landscape--*/

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .navbar-brand img {
        width: 500px;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        width: 500px;
    }
    .nav-item {
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }


    #home h1 {
        color: blue;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 80px 60px;
    }
    .content-box-lg {
        height: 600px;
        margin: 80px 20px;
    }

    .content-box-page {
        height: 476px;
        margin: 80px 60px 40px 70px;
    }

    #contact-info br {
        display: block;
    }
    #contact-info i {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    #about-content img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 130px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn-clients {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


    #service-content .col-lg-3 {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #provider-content img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #provider-contact {
        width: 94%;
    }

    .provider-specialty h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .provider-specialty {
        background: rgba(0, 163, 204, .8);
        border-radius: 20px;;
        margin: 10px 0 20px 0px;
        padding-left: 20px;

}
/*
    .content-box-xl {
        margin: 0 70px 30px 70px;
    }
*/
    @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991.98px) {
        #home h1 {
            color: pink;
        }
    }
/*--- Medium Devices (portrait tablets/small desktop)--IPadAir2Portrait*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    #home h1 {
        color: red;
    }
    #home-content-inner h6 {
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 650px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 15px;
        left: -100px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #home-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -90px;

    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;

    }
    .nav-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        display: none;
    }

    #clients h2,
    #providers h2 {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    #clients hr,
    #providers hr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #providers p {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #clients p {
        line-height: 28px;
    }

    #providers p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    #clients p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #providers ul {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    #clients img,
    #providers img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 46%
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 60px 60px 100px 60px;
    }

    #contact-info br {
        display: block;
    }
    #contact-info i {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    #about-content img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }



    .content-box-page {
        height: 768px;
        margin: 30px 60px 100px 60px;
    }
    #provider-content img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #provider-contact {
        width: 94%;
    }

    .provider-specialty h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .provider-specialty {
        background: rgba(0, 163, 204, .8);
        border-radius: 20px;;
        margin: 10px 0 20px 0px;
        padding-left: 20px;

}


}

/*--Iphone 7 Plus landscape --*/

@media (min-width: 736px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
    #home h1 {
        color: yellow;
    }
    #home-content-inner h6 {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 570px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 15px;
        left: -90px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #home-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -90px;

    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
        left: 6px;
    }
    .btn-providers {
        position: relative;
        right: 114%;
        bottom: 60px;
    }
    .visible-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        position: relative;
        left: 70%;
        bottom: 80px;
    }
    #clients h2,
    #providers h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #clients hr,
    #providers hr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #providers {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    #providers p {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #clients p {
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    #clients p,
    #providers p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #providers ul {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #clients img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        left: 30px;
    }
    #providers img {
        width: 80%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: auto;
        margin: 40px 40px 0 40px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .content-box-lg {
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px
    }
    #contact form {
        height: 615px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .btn-form {
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
    }

    .service-info {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/*---Google Nexus 7 Portrait 600 --*/

@media (min-width: 611px) and (max-width: 735.98px) {
    #home h1 {
        color: black;
    }
    #home-content-inner h6 {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 540px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 15px;
        left: -110px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #home-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -90px;

    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
        left: 6px;
    }
    .btn-providers {
        position: relative;
        right: 114%;
        bottom: 60px;
    }
    .visible-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        position: relative;
        left: 70%;
        bottom: 85px;
    }
    #clients h2,
    #providers h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #clients hr,
    #providers hr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #providers {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    #providers p {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #clients p {
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    #clients p,
    #providers p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #providers ul {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #clients img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        left: 30px;
    }
    #providers img {
        width: 80%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: auto;
        margin: 40px 40px 0 40px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .content-box-lg {
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px
    }
    #contact form {
        height: 615px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .btn-form {
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
    }

    .service-info {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .box {
        position: relative;
        left: -20px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


}

/*--- Small Devices (landscape phones/?portrait tablets?) Galaxys7 landscape--*/

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 610.98px) {
    #home h1 {
        color: orange;
    }

    #home-content-inner h6 {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 540px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 15px;
        left: -110px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #home-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -90px;

    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
        left: 6px;
    }
    .btn-providers {
        position: relative;
        right: 114%;
        bottom: 60px;
    }
    .visible-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    .hidden-btn {
        position: relative;
        left: 70%;
        bottom: 85px;
    }
    #clients h2,
    #providers h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #clients hr,
    #providers hr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #providers {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    #providers p {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #clients p {
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    #clients p,
    #providers p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #providers ul {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #clients img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        left: 30px;
    }
    #providers img {
        width: 80%;
        height: 37%;
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: auto;
        margin: 40px 40px 0 40px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .content-box-lg {
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px
    }
    #contact form {
        height: 615px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .btn-form {
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
    }

    .service-info {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }


}

/*-----Phone Landscape- (Apple Iphone SE Only)----*/

@media (min-width: 568px) and (max-width: 575.98px) {

    #home h1 {
        color: green;
    }
    #home-content-inner h6 {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 540px;
        height: 60px;
        top: -30px;
        left: -80px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #home-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        top: 0px;
        left: -100px;
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
        left: 6px;
    }

    .hidden-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    #clients h2,
    #providers h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #clients hr,
    #providers hr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #providers {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    #providers p {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    #clients p {
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    #clients p,
    #providers p {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #providers ul {
        margin-top: 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #clients img {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #providers img {
        width: 60%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
    }
    .content-box-md {
        height: auto;
        margin: 40px 40px 0 40px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #clients {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .content-box-lg {
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px
    }
    #contact form {
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .btn-form {
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
    }


}
```

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: You do realize there's no such thing as pixels that aren't whole numbers right? You can't very well light up 98% of one and leave the rest of it to something else.

Comment: Also you have syntax errors in your existing code, like a backtick in the `laptop 1366` rule.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: That of course depends on the user's device. On some high resolution devices a CSS `px` covers multiple physical pixels.

Comment: @AlexP I actually didn't know that. But that still doesn't equate to 98% of one pixel like the media query is trying to target. That's just a ratio.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra ' in min at 1366px

```
/*---laptop 1366---*/
@media (mi`/* <-- REMOVE THIS ` */ n-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1499.98px) {
    .nav-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: That tick is actually not in my original code. It just happened while I was trying to post the question sorry. The whole ctrl+k thing messed me up, I'm new at this. But it seems to happen in my CSS sheets as of late. It stops reading my code after a certain line for some reason. If I move that code up somewhere else, it will work, but everything underneath like line 650 will stop working. Is it a memory issue or something? When I moved it to a new external css file, it started working in there.